# Visual studio 2015 ts file editor don't show Angular 2 syntax and suggestion in editior

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Hi every body i have problem with my VS 2015 that editor not show Angular 2 syntax and suggestion panel in editior. see the link below pls:

[image: Angular js 2 editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is something wrong with the type script plugin， try reinstall or update the plugin.

another option is use VSCode to edit typescript files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl + Shift + X` to show all extensions. Pick whatever the plugin you want and download it.